# How do I just select the "occupation"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT '{"people": [{"name": "Bob", "occupation": "janitor"}, {"name": "Susan", "occupation": "CEO"}]}'::jsonb as data
) as b 
WHERE data->'people' @> '[{"name":"Bob"}]'::jsonb;
```

I am filtering for the object '{"name": "Bob", "occupation": "janitor"}'

How do I return Bob's occupation ("janitor")?

```
SELECT data->'people'->>'occupation'  
FROM (
   SELECT '{"people": [{"name": "Bob", "occupation": "janitor"}, {"name": "Susan", "occupation": "CEO"}]}'::jsonb as data
) as b 
WHERE data->'people' @> '[{"name":"Bob"}]'::jsonb;
```

returns

```
?column?
--------
NULL
```

Looking for:

```
occupation
----------
janitor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about anything else on the row where the jsonb is, you can take all elements out of the jsonb and then use them as separate elements to select from

```
SELECT data->>'occupation' as occupation
FROM (
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements(
    '{"people": 
       [
         {"name": "Bob", "occupation": "janitor"}, 
         {"name": "Susan", "occupation": "CEO"}
       ]
     }'::jsonb->'people') as data) as b
WHERE data @> '{"name":"Bob"}';
```

Results

> occupation
>   -----------
>    janitor
>   (1 row)

Comment: Good answer, hope you don't mind the formatting.  You could select `data->>'occuption'` to avoid the double quotes in the result.

Comment: @Andomar Thanks, missed that. Editing in

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: That works, thanks again! What index do I need for jsonb_array_elements? I couldn't find any information here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html

Comment: This really helped 1

Answer (score 0):

Your "people" element is an array.  You can get at the elements of an array with the [`jsonb_array_elements`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) function.  After that, you can just filter on `person->>'name'`:

```
SELECT  person->>'occupation' as occupation
FROM    (
        SELECT  person.value as person
        FROM    (
                SELECT     
                  '{"people": 
                     [
                       {"name": "Bob", "occupation": "janitor"}, 
                       {"name": "Susan", "occupation": "CEO"}
                     ]
                   }'::jsonb as data
                ) a
        CROSS JOIN
                jsonb_array_elements(data->'people') as person
        ) b
WHERE   person->>'name' = 'Bob';
```

Note that `->>` returns text, while `->` returns `jsonb`.